# aspnet_regsql not generating all tables

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

For some weird reason, `aspnet_regsql` command only generates some and not all the tables in Membership database. For example, it doesn't generate dbo.Users, dbo.Roles, dbo.Profile etc. In fact it generates only 11 of the 17 tables. I have tried running it from the command prompt with different switches. Plus I have run it as admin too. No better. Does anyone know what am I missing here?

This is ASP.NET 4.0 + SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: What directory are you running it from?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Answer (score 1):

Right. Figured this out after a long day of effort. Here's the summary if anyone else needs it:

1. ASP.NET 4.0 includes a new set of providers that reside in a different namespace `System.Web.Providers.DefaultXProvider`, where X can be Membership, Role, Profile or SessionState. You should really use these in your web.config if you're targeting ASP.NET 4.0 or above. You can download these providers through NuGet by searching for **Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core** package.
2. The new providers do not use "aspnet_" prefix with the table names. So what used to be **dbo.aspnet_Roles** in previous versions is now **dbo.Roles** and so on. The new providers use only 6 tables. I had incorrectly created tables through both the old and the new providers on my development machine and that's why I thought it was missing some tables on the production server.
3. You do not need to explicitly run `aspnet_regsql` on your database. The first time you access your database through a Membership call, such as `GetUser()`, the provider will automatically generate the required tables for you if they do not already exist.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: i know this have many years, but i'm today implementing in an old machine this feature. 
If it works, i will came here to tell. :) but i case i forgot, i created the database and it was without tables